# SSH works in Remmina but not in Terminal nor Putty

Tags: ssh

I was able to connect to my server using SSH normally using Terminal but suddenly it didn’t connect.

I tried PuTTY as well and ended up with no luck. However when I tried remmina it successfully connected to my server. I’ve tried the workarounds around the net for similar problems but none of the worked. In addition it seems everybody always could connect using putty. But I’m not. Could somebody present a workaround for this please?

These are the last line of running `ssh server -vvv`:

```
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Comment: show the error you are getting, and try something like ssh -v

Comment: added to the post.

Comment: also i don't get any errors. it just gets stuck.

Comment: i'm not familiar but I googled the last line, does anything here help? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1254085    e.g. `ssh -c 3des-cbc <targethost>`   also see http://serverfault.com/questions/210408/ssh-access-problem-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-reply

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tested this command and still no luck. I've also tested other ways in the links you provided. no luck.

Comment: you could try the newsgroup comp.security.ssh